# Trigger Mysql Update en un campo para que se autosume formato TIME

Tags: mysql, funciones, date, trigger, timestamp

estoy intentando poner un trigger para autocalcular unas horas.
Si es el mismo día solo tiene que sacar la diferencia, si es diferente día lo que tiene que hacer es sacar la diferencia hasta las 24:00:00

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `TotalHoras` 
AFTER INSERT ON `Servicio` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if DATEDIFF(FechaInicio, FechaFin)=0 THEN 
INSERT INTO Servicio (TotalHoras) VALUES (SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , HoraInicio, HoraFin)*60));

ELSE 
SET @findia := SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , HoraInicio, horafinal)*60); 
SET @findia := SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE , HoraFin, @findia)*60); 

INSERT INTO Servicio (TotalHoras) VALUES (SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE , HoraFin, @findia))*60); 

END if ; 
END
```

No me da problemas a la hora de guardar.
Campos de donde saco los datos:

[image: Campos de donde saco los datos]

Campo donde quiero guardar el calculo:

[image: Campo donde quiero guardar el calculo]

Cuando hago una inserción:

[image: Pantalla de los datos que agrego]

Error:

[image: Error que aparece]

No entiendo el mensaje que sale, creo que todos los formatos coinciden como 00:00:00.

Imagen con los datos en select, como que los formatos son todos iguales y el resultado de la operación es el correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias :)

Comment: Saludos. Hace falta más detalle; te comento de momento lo siguiente; leyendo respecto a TIMESTAMPDIFF (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) los ejemplos muestran que incluye **día, mes** y **año** al parecer puede ser opcional la hora (hora, minuto, segundos..) ahora bien te sugiero revises `HoraInicio` y `HoraFin` contenga los datos necesario, para la función que los recibe.

Comment: Como no se poner aquí la imagen del resultado con los formatos he editado la parte superior, revise los datos y el enlace que me has pasado, pero no me cuadra que el select si que funcione y cuando hago el insert no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado :)

El problema era que estaba intentado hacer un insert... y no update... lógicamente cuando estaba haciendo un insert le mandaba hacer el trigger con otro insert en la misma tabla y faltaban campos por rellenar.

Al cambiar el insert por el update, me daba fallo porque el insert anterior bloqueaba el update dado que el registro en esa tabla aun estaba bloqueado, con lo que he optado por poner el siguiente codigo en un trigger que ya tenia para guardar en otra tabla que tenia intermedia.

```
IF (DATEDIFF(NEW.FechaInicio, NEW.FechaFin)=0) THEN

SET @findia := SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , NEW.HoraInicio, NEW.HoraFin)*60);

ELSE

SET @findia := SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , HoraInicio, horafinal)*60);
SET @findia := SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE , HoraFin, @findia)*60);

END if ;
```

Con este código mas el cambio del insert por update solucionado :)